# WCF: Supressing FaultExceptions & ObjectDataSource Binding

Tags: wcf, generics, objectdatasource

I had designed a *web service* which, upon each method call, would return a structure of some type `T` if the request were successfully conducted, or otherwise throw a `FaultException` to the client to signal some error. One of the client applications was an ASP.NET application with a bunch of `ObjectDataSource` objects directly tied to the methods of the service. Those objects would take care of things such as GridView paging or DropDown populating for themselves.

Unfortunately, I was just now ordered to remove all `FaultException` from the service and wrap the types I was returning into a generic `ServiceResponse<T>` structure which wraps the original return structure of type `T` and adds some more fields to transmit exception information. Having no other choice, I did this right away and replaced all the old service proxy calls with a call to a generic `ExecuteMethod<TChannel, TReturn>` method which takes care for itself of unwrapping the value if the request was successful or throw some exception otherwise. The problem now is that, since this new method is generic, I can't tie an `ObjectDataSource` to it, and GridView automatic paging is gone.

Since `ObjectDataSource` doesn't support generic methods, nor it supports generic classes without a lot of mangling with assembly-qualified types names which I would like to avoid, I am left with the options of either page the GridView manually, which I would like to avoid as well, or writing a proxy to wrap every necessary service call and return the desired value, which then is "wrapping a wrapper". Can you please help me decide which one will not be the worst? Do I have any other options in this case?

Comment: Please could you avoid deleting question text so that others who find this question can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the "wrapping a wrapper" approach as you call it. Architecturally it's entirely valid since each has a single responsibility.

It will be a pain to maintain if the service contract is not stable but it's probably more maintainable than the assembly qualified name approach will be in the same circumstances.

(RANT: As an aside I trust the person who "ordered" you to remove the Faults from the service understands the impacts this will have on interoperability of the service. Also, the approach allows the service implementors and consumers to get themselves into difficulty if they fail to properly implement your new proprietary protocol. It seems like it doesn't actually achieve anything anyway since all you're changing is the mechanism by which a Fault gets converted to an Exception at the client.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that is what I will end up doing. And trust me... he doesn't.